# Importing JSON that starts with an array

Tags: arrays, json, excel, xpath

I am trying to use excel to import and show a JSON. I've got this working for most JSONs. With this particular JSON, it starts with an array and I don't know how the parseOptions syntax to address and array first and then objects.I have successfully used `=IMPORTJSON("url", "object to call")` I want to display the '[0]/metadata/last_name' for each array object.

here is my code:

```
=IMPORTJSON("https://api.sleeper.app/v1/draft/547633764530618368/picks","[0]/metadata/last_name")
```

Here is my JSON:

```
[
 {
  "round":1,
  "roster_id":null,
  "player_id":"4866",
  "picked_by":"448639868432543744",
  "pick_no":1,
  "metadata":{
    "years_exp":"2",
    "team":"NYG",
    "status":"Active",
    "sport":"nfl",
    "position":"RB",
    "player_id":"4866",
    "number":"26",
    "news_updated":"1577679319834",
    "last_name":"Barkley",
    "injury_status":"",
    "first_name":"Saquon"
 },
 "is_keeper":null,
 "draft_slot":1,
 "draft_id":"547633764530618368"
 },
 {
  "round":1,
  "roster_id":null,
  "player_id":"4046",
  "picked_by":"341432375512702976",
  "pick_no":2,
  "metadata":{
    "years_exp":"3",
    "team":"KC",
    "status":"Active",
    "sport":"nfl",
    "position":"QB",
    "player_id":"4046",
    "number":"15",
    "news_updated":"1583891151374",
    "last_name":"Mahomes",
    "injury_status":"",
    "first_name":"Patrick"
 },
 "is_keeper":null,
 "draft_slot":2,
 "draft_id":"547633764530618368"
 },
 {
  "round":1,
  "roster_id":null,
  "player_id":"4881",
  "picked_by":"539512871341760512",
  "pick_no":3,
  "metadata":{
    "years_exp":"2",
    "team":"BAL",
    "status":"Active",
    "sport":"nfl",
    "position":"QB",
    "player_id":"4881",
    "number":"8",
    "news_updated":"1580608524794",
    "last_name":"Jackson",
    "injury_status":"Probable",
    "first_name":"Lamar"
 },
 "is_keeper":null,
 "draft_slot":3,
 "draft_id":"547633764530618368"
 }
```

Comment: I haven't used `IMPORTJSON`. Where did you get it?  I have mostly used [VBA-JSON](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON)

Comment: Not sure exactly what you want for output, but `Power Query` can parse that JSON starting with the [url](https://api.sleeper.app/v1/draft/547633764530618368/picks) and then converting the list of records to tables.

Comment: Excel 2020 doesn't have Power Query. I used IMPORTJSON which is a function of excel.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured the first part out. code looks like this:

\\
=IMPORTJSON("https://api.sleeper.app/v1/draft/547633764530618368/picks","0/metadata/first_name")
\\

But now I'm trying to have the cells run through a FOR Loop of the array. So it starts at 0 (as in 0/metadata/first_name), but how do I set it in a loop so that each cell increased the array number?